# What perl version will be in 12.04 LTS

Tags: lts, perl, 12.04

Pretty soon the new 12.04 version of ubuntu will be released. My question is what version of perl language will be in this distribution.

And my second version where can this information be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you meant 12.04 LTS. 11.04 is not a LTS, the previous LTS is 10.04.

According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/perl, Ubuntu 12.04 will have Perl 5.14.2. On the same site you'll find other packages. Do note that packages are [directly copied from Debian](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTSDebianImportFreeze) until 29th December 2011 according to the [Release Schedule for 12.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I've meant 12.04 of course.